# After updating rails 2.3.2 to 2.3.15 destroys scandic charset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, character-encoding, actionviewhelper

We have problem with scandic charset.

We have localization file as *.yml and database which contains also some localization.

Problem is that when we use Actionview helper it destroys scandic charset by removing characters from the string.

If we use normal html tags like span or p then it works just fine.

Any ideas why the problem is only with helpers?